# IP to Location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

I can get User IP by this code...

I want to find location of this IP.
How can I?

Comment: What do you mean by the "location?" Latitude/longitude?

Comment: be aware the Lat/Long you get is probably not very accurate. My IP address at home shows up about 30 miles away from where I'm actually located; it shows where my ISP is.  This could be "good enough" depending on what you're doing, but you should understand the limitations.

Comment: the question is not about programming as is, but how to get "location" from an "IP"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can submit the IP you receive to an online geolocation service, such as `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=<your ip here>&jsoncallback=<suitable javascript function in your source>`, then including the source it returns which will run the function you specify in `jsoncallback` with the geolocation information.

Alternatively, you may want to look into HTML5's geolocation features -- you can see a demo of it in action [here](http://html5demos.com/geo). The advantage of this is that you do not need to make requests to foreign servers, but it may not work on browsers that do not support HTML5.

Comment: how can I call this api in my javascript without running into cors issues?

Comment: For a list of all free IP lookup services, you can refer to my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: Also now (2021), this Service needs paid subscription to be able to use `https` instead of `http`. Using `http` in API inside a `https` hosted site will be blocked by the browser.

Answer (score 32):

A free open source community run geolocation ip service that runs on the MaxMind database is available here:
https://ipstack.com/

**Example**

```
https://api.ipstack.com/160.39.144.19
```

**Limitation**

10,000 queries per month

Comment: Although freegeoip.net uses MaxMind database, the service has absolutely no relation with the company. It is an open source and free software supported by the community and maintained by myself, without the consent of MaxMind.

Comment: It has been moved to https://ipstack.com and they offer paid services now. However, the 10,000 queries limit for free license should be sufficient. Just note, that it's not per hour anymore, it's per month.

Comment: They dont support api calls over https for free plan

Answer (score 20):

It's quite easy with an [API](https://ipapi.co/#api) that maps IP address to location. Run the snippet to get city & country for the IP in the input box.

```js
$('.send').on('click', function(){

  $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/'+$('.ip').val()+'/json', function(data){
      $('.city').text(data.city);
      $('.country').text(data.country);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="ip" value="8.8.8.8">
<button class="send">Go</button>
<br><br>
<span class="city"></span>, 
<span class="country"></span>
```

Comment: Now (2021), This code snippet, on running inside SO, throws CORS error, their tech support says that there is some issue with CORS when API returns an error response. In my research, it throws a 404 error. I don't know why it throws that error. Same CORS error when running in localhost on some port, they reported that they have some issue with port. Even after hosting on CloudFront, it's the same CORS error, cannot figure out anything else.

Answer (score 8):

A better way is to skip the "middle man" (ip)

```
jQuery.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```

This gives you the **IP**, the **city**, the **country**, etc

Comment: Is there any limitations to how often you can do this?

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you were not able to accomplish the above code, here is a simple way of using it with jquery:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",
    function (data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            document.write('data["i"] = ' + i + '<br/>');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The new url is http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp, the IP is not necessary but it is less precise (the lat-long) than freegeoip

Comment: This service does not have SSL - so is blocked by Chrome, etc....

Comment: @CFPSupport yep these days http requests are being block so we might, they have https support but it will cost https://www.geoplugin.com/premium#ssl_access_per_year

Answer (score 3):

A rather inexpensive option would be to use the [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-4937517&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) API, it's free upto 1500 requests a day.

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-4937517-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

```js
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#city").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<h1><a href="https://ipdata.co">ipdata.co</a> - IP geolocation API</h1>

<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<pre id="response"></pre>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

View the Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ipdata/6wtf0q4g/922/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ipgeolocation](https://ipgeolocation.io/) which is a free IP API that provides country, city, state, province, latitude, longitude and etc.

```
 let apiKey = "your_api_key_here"; 

  async function getLocation (ip) {
  let url = `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=${apiKey}&ip=${ip}`;

  await fetch(url).then((response) =>
    response.json().then((json) => {
      const output = `
          ---------------------
          Country: ${json.country_name}
          State: ${json.state_prov}
          City: ${json.city}
          District: ${json.district}
          Lat / Long: (${json.latitude}, ${json.longitude})
          ---------------------
          `;
      console.log(output);
    })
  );
};

 getLocation('154.28.188.208') // prints the location
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this google service [free IP geolocation webservice](http://freegeoip.appspot.com/)

**update**

the link is broken, I put here other link that include @NickSweeting in the comments:

[ip-api.com](http://ip-api.com/)

and you can get the data in json format:

http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: You should delete your comment that says the same.

Comment: @10basetom Geoip services regularly go down since they are expensive to operate and tend to get a lot of free traffic.  Here are some alternatives that work as of 2015/01: http://ip-api.com/json http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.8

Answer (score 2):

Either one of the following links should take care of this:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

http://www.adam-mcfarland.net/2009/11/19/simple-ip-geolocation-using-javascript-and-the-google-ajax-search-api/

Those links have tutorials for getting a users location through Javascript. However, they do so through an API to an external data service. If you have an extremely high traffic site, you might want to hosting the data yourself (or getting a premium api service). To host everything yourself, you will have to host a database with IP Geolocation and use ajax to feed the users location into Javascript. If this is the approach you want to take, you can get a free database of IP information below:

http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

Please note that this method entails having to periodically update the database to stay accurate in tracing ips to locations.

Comment: The Google API version at adam-mcfarland.net is perfect for what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: this has been shutdown!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) after getting your api key you can query for a location against a specific ip like this `http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=" + apiKey + "&ip=" + ip + "&output=xml` you can then then extract the location from the xml response

Answer (score -1):

Try TUQ GEO IP API it's free and really neat and sweet with jsonp support

http://tuq.in/tools/geo

http://tuq.in/tools/geo+stats

Comment: dead link.. not working...