# Display message for international users

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I would like to display a pop-up when international visitors visit my U.S. bases website. Preferably with javascript or the jQuery framework. Any recommendations?

Comment: You want to determine if visitor IP addresses are from another country, so this might be a helpful SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript - but I don't know what you really need to know, like if it's detecting foreign IP addresses or what.

Comment: A different approach would be to see if the browser language is English or not. The search term for that is "localization". [Here is one jQuery approach for it.](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery, http://smart-ip.net/, and https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$.cookie("international")) {
        $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){
            if (data.countryCode !== "US") {
                popUpFunction();
                $.cookie("international", "yes", { expires: 365 });
            } else {
                $.cookie("international", "no", { expires: 365 });
            }
        });
    } else {
        if ($.cookie("international") === "yes") {
            popUpFunction();
        }
    }
});
```