# Redirect website according to the users country

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I want to redirect my site according to users country. For example if user type www.domain.com from USA, then he should redirect to en.domain.com.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I want USA users to see my site in english, german users to see it in german, once they type main domain URL. Mean redirect automatically to there subdomain according to there country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to get you started, here's how you can detect a person's country, using HTML5 Geolocation:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': <YOURLATLNGRESPONSEFROMGEO>}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var loc = getCountry(results);
            }
        }
    });

function getCountry(results)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
    {
    var shortname = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
    var longname = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    var type = results[0].address_components[i].types;
    if (type.indexOf("country") != -1)
    {
        if (!isNullOrWhitespace(shortname))
        {
            return shortname;
        }
        else
        {
            return longname;
        }
    }
}

}

function isNullOrWhitespace(text) {
    if (text == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return text.replace(/\s/gi, '').length < 1;
}
```

That will get the country of the person. Unfortunately, there is no way that I know of to use that to redirect a person. Try out this link: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location like described here:

[IP to Location using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript)

and then redirect accordingly