# How can I detect the visitor's location using JavaScript, and call a JavaScript function on the basis of a certain location?

Tags: javascript, blogger-dynamic-views

I am using Blogger  for blogging and if a visitor comes from USA i want to display certain banner or link or advertisement.

Comment: One technique used for broad location is to take the user's IP address and look up the approximate location based on that.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript) for one way to do that.

Comment: You're looking for the geolocation API.

Comment: See [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation) for how to obtain lat/long for a user and then convert into a physical location.