# Adding image with text on google maps for web

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps, markers

I've been lately trying to figure out a way to have text and image on google maps for web.

For example, I have 2 friends, I want them to be displayed on the map; *their image with their name.*

So far all that I found was using JavaScript libraries that can only insert labels on the map.

Is it possible to do what I'm thinking or not? What's the name of the library if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, it is possible as long as you can get the long/lat coordinates of your friends.
Once you have that you can add labels onto google maps api.

Comment: Your answer did cheer me up :D
How is it possible though?

Comment: The chosen answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript will get you the long/lat, given it's not the most accurate, but within a ballpark figure of the town the user is located in. Once you have that you can add the coordinates to google maps api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates