# How to use Google Maps location with IP instead of requesting user to access location

Tags: autocomplete, maps

Currently I have

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: geolocation,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        places.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
}
```

and want to use something like

```
if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {

    var latitude = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
    var longitude = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
    var city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
    var country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
    var country_code = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
    var region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
```

I would like to use IP address instead of requesting user access.

Comment: Have you tried something like https://ipinfo.io?

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript