# how to detect when user is using mock location chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, mobile, desktop

Is there a way to detect when user is mocking his location in chrome browser (mobile and desktop)?
Tried googling but i only see how to actually mock and how to detect in native mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only) to see how to get the client's IP address. Most of the services mentioned in that question will also return the IP address's location, and thus allow you to compare it to the location provided by the geolocation API. If the service does not provide the location, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937517/ip-to-location-using-javascript) to convert the IP address into a location.